# how do I build a chromium dist (preferably zip) for linix?

Tags: chrome

I have successfully built a chromium dist. I used [this guide](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code).

Now I have a working chrome executable in my `~/chromium/src/out/Default` folder.

So far so good. But the resulting build directory is 24GB which is obviously not something I can zip and use on other Linux machines.

How do I create a distributable dist for Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I'm getting close so i'm going to share what I've got so far and update as I go along...

First there is a Google mailing list for [Google Packagers](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-packagers) Go ahead and join that group if you need to ask questions (I sure did).

And here is a post from that group that helps install how to get the `.deb` installer.

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/3PXe8AxbW1s

Here they say what to do (slightly modified to avoid errors)

1. cd to the `src` directory
2. Run `gn args out/Release` (A vi window will appear) and add these lines

> ```
> is_component_build = false
> is_debug = false
> symbol_level = 0
> enable_nacl = true
> remove_webcore_debug_symbols = true
> enable_linux_installer = true
> ```

And save.

3. List out the possible installer targets available by using this command:
   `ninja -C out/Release -t targets all | grep installer`
4. To build a release of one of these targets (for example Debian) run:
   `ninja -C out/Release "chrome/installer/linux:unstable_deb"`
5. When it finishes, obtain your installer from the `out/Release` directory.

For me, it created: `chromium-browser-unstable_67.0.3368.0-1_amd64.deb`

6. Now use `ar` to extract the debian file: 
   `ar x chromium-browser-unstable_67.0.3368.0-1_amd64.deb`
7. Now extract the two tar files within: 
   `tar xvf data.tar && tar xvf control.tar.gz`
8. at this point, you should be able to launch chrome from: 
   `./opt/chromium.org/chromium-unstable/chromium-browser-unstable`

These last few steps of extracting the debian are a hack. Working on getting in zip format from the ninja + python processes within chromium src.

Comment: The advantage to using a deb or rpm is the dependency management.  If you don't want that, you can always convert the deb or rpm file to a tar.gz using `alien`

Comment: thanks @ivanivan i never heard of alien. will look at it

Comment: Hey @ivanivan can you let me know how `alien` would alter this process? I wasn't able to figure out the correlation to how that would make this easier.